Is differential follow up periods in survival analysis a problem?
I'm looking to compare mortality post-operatively following two different surgical techniques. due to technological advances, one of these surgical techniques was only performed around five years after the other one. however both techniques are now commonly practiced. as a result, i have a group of patients whose follow up period lags around five years behind the other. is this a problem when doing kaplan meier survival analysis or computing a hazard ratio using cox regression? the kaplan meier plot appears five years longer for one intervention than the other.
thanks

After the last post-surgery observation time for the group with the newer surgery method, no such patient will be in the risk set for events among those who received the older method. At those later times the value for method for an individual having an event will be the same as the average over those still at risk, so those later times provide no information for solving the score vector to fit the model and estimate the regression coefficient for method (although they will contribute to estimates of other predictors).
I'd worry more about modeling the association of calendar date with outcome for both surgeries. Particularly with a new method, technique improves with time. Although I don't generally like throwing away data, it might be safest to restrict the study to times after the adoption of the newer method. There's also the question of whether the choice of surgical method depends on other outcome-associated clinical variables.

thanks. so just to clarify about the first part of your reply, theres nothing i need to do to make the two groups have similar follow up periods or something?

@MFA If you limit the analysis to surgeries performed since the newer method was adopted, which I think is very wise here, then that problem takes care of itself. There might well have been improvements in other clinical care methods over time, leading to better survival in later calendar years regardless of surgical method. If so, that would unfairly penalize the older surgical method; you would tend to compare the older surgical method, with cases weighted to the older other clinical care methods, against the newer surgical method with newer clinical care methods.

@MFA to address your comment directly, those longer follow-up times won't enter into the estimates of the regression coefficient for comparing the surgical methods. But I suspect that a reviewer would question why you included those early old-method cases that lead to the longer follow-up times at all, for reasons I outlined in my other comment.

thanks very much
